# Correct frame-ancestors Configuration

Tags: iframe, content-security-policy

I have a public, SSL enabled site - https://server1.com

I have another public, non-SSL enabled site - http://subdomain.server2.com

I have set the *Content-Security-Policy* for the first site to be: 
`Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' 'http://*.server2.com`

I have a page on server 2 that loads a page on server 1 in an iframe, however I get the error

> Refused to display 'https://www.server1.com/some_page' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'self' http://*.server2.com".

Any ideas as to why this doesn't work? I'm assuming I don't have the write format for my frame-ancestors value, however everything I've found online seems to tell me this is correct.

Comment: Can you post if you have a CSP defined for the second site? Also, when you say "I have a page on server 2 that loads a page on server 1 in an iframe", is your main page on server1 or server2? Your error message appears to indicate server2 is the iframe content and server1 is the main page.

Comment: I've updated the error message. The iframe content is a page on server 1. Server 2 hosts the iframe itself. There is no CSP header on server 2.

Comment: Note that frame-ancestors will not take priority in firefox, see this bug https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1024557 and upvote it to try get this fixed.